# Simplifying a complex number into $a + bi$ form

Tags: complex-numbers

I am trying to write $3^i$ in $a + bi $ form. I know

$$ 3^i = e^{i \log 3 } = e^{ i ( \log 3 + 2 \pi k ) }= e^{i \log 3} e^{2 \pi ki} = e^{i \log 3} = \cos ( \log 3 ) + i \sin( \log 3) $$

is this correct?

Comment: What's the reason with two equalities between $e^{i\log 3}$ and $e^{i\log 3}$?

Comment: It is correct but, as A.G. commented, you can do it shorter $3^i = e^{i \log 3 } =  \cos ( \log 3 ) + i \sin( \log 3)$

Comment: @A.G. I suspect the OP means the $\log$ at the beginning to be a (multivalued) complex logarithm and that at the end to be the (single valued) logarithm of a positive real.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you want all possible values,
$$3^i=e^{i\log3}=e^{i(\ln3+2\pi k i)}$$
and so on (I am using $\ln$ to denote the natural logarithm of a real number).  Note that you have a couple of small errors in your working.

Comment: The unexplained anonymous downvote Mafia strikes again!